# Sqlite Query produce Nullpointer Exception?

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

why SqlLite query in android produce Nullpointer exception I am using this code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
   String newTableQueryString = "create table " +TABLE_NAME +" (" +
                                    TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                                    TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text," +
                                    TABLE_ROW_TWO + " text" +
                                    ");";
Log.e("check","table have been created"+newTableQueryString);
        try{

            mdb.execSQL(newTableQueryString);//it produce exce[ption
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception"," "+ e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: mdb is reference of DataBaseManager class which contains code of table creation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is mdb is null when you call:

```
 mdb.execSQL(newTableQueryString);
```

Did you mean to invoke the execSQL method on the db method parameter that you're passing into the onCreate method?

Comment: this method is present in class DataBaseManager and I am making object of This class in Resume Method of launching Activity.

Comment: Take a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).  The onResume() method is not invoked until after onCreate(), so that is why mdb is null in the onCreate method.